# Apply search in SharePoint Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, caml-query, sharepoint-rest-api

> I want to apply **Search** functionality  only on **Custom List** in
>   SharePoint using Rest API or CAML query.

- I already tried that **rest api** example:

  ```
  $.getJSON("https://SharePointURL/_api/search/query?
  querytext='QueryText*+Path:https://SharePointListPath", function(data){
      console.log(data);
  });
  ```

but it take too much of `JSON` data. Therefore any example to make it simple.

Visit this URL: [Calling SharePoint Search Using Rest](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/calling-sharepoint-search-using-rest-eg.html)

Go through this code:

```
function getSearchResultsUsingREST(queryText) {
    // search can use the app web URL as the base, so no need to use SP.AppContextSite(@target) to access the host web..
    var searchUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + queryText + "'";
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url: searchUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: onGetSearchResultsSuccess,
            error: onGetSearchResultsFail
        }
    );
}

function onGetSearchResultsSuccess(data) {
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
    var results = jsonObject.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;
    if (results.length == 0) {
        $('#related-content-results').text('No related documents were found');
    }
    else {
        var searchResultsHtml = '';
        $.each(results, function (index, result) {
            searchResultsHtml += "<a target='_blank' href='" + result.Cells.results[6].Value + "'>" + result.Cells.results[3].Value + "</a> (" + result.Cells.results[10].Value + ")<br />";
        });
        $('#related-content-results').html(searchResultsHtml);
    }
}

function onGetSearchResultsFail(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
    $('#related-content-results').text('An error occurred whilst searching for related content - ' + errorMessage);
}
```

but `var results` take 48 cells which doesn't contain **Custom List** field.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the REST endpoint for additional Fields explicitly with:

`&selectproperties=[internalName],[internaleName]`

#### SharePoint endpoint and Search documentation

- URI Conventions (OData Version 2.0)
  http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/
- Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx

Search has different syntax

- SharePoint Search REST API overview
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8a4f7863-e4c1-4099-9189-a1894db36930%28office.15%29.aspx
- FAST Query Language (FQL) syntax reference
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394606.aspx

iSearch

Comment: Please! put some `code` rather than link.

Comment: Okay, that ``selectproperties`` IS code. It is clear you know nothing about REST endpoints and are probably copy/pasting code you do not understand. RTFM!

Comment: What `[internalName]` suppose to. Is it custom field name inside custom list.

Comment: Read the F* Manual